# Check equality of an objects array property and a nested object property

Tags: javascript

On my app I'm checking the equality between an objects array property and a nested object property - based on the results I return a new objects array.

The `items` objects array:

```
[{name: 'test', value: 1, category: 'a'},{name: 'test2', value: 2, category: 'b'},{name: 'test3', value: 3, category: 'c'}]
```

The `itemList` object:

```
{testnum1: {name: 'test123', category: 'a'}, testnum2: {name: 'test234', category: 'b'}
```

I need to check the equality between the `category` properties and return the following objects array:

```
[{name: 'test', itemCategory: 'testnum1'},{name: 'test2', itemCategory: 'testnum2'}]
```

This is what I did, any idea on how to make it more readable?

```
const getCategorizedItems = items => {
  const itemListCategories = Object.keys(itemList)
  const categorizedItems= items.map(item=> {
    const itemCategory = itemListCategories.find(category =>
      item.category === itemList[category].category 
    )
    if (itemCategory ) return {name: item.name, category: itemCategory }
  })
  .filter(f => f)
  return categorizedItems
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. Please add to your question how the code presented is going to be used: What is it good for? (Re)Visit [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short review;

- Unless you are writing inline functions, you should stick to using `function`
- Using semicolons is preferred, it takes skill and knowledge to avoid the pitfalls of not using semicolons
- You assign in 1 statement the value of `categorizedItems` and `return` it in the next, you might as well `return` immediately
- In essence you do a `find` within a `map`, not too fast, I would create a lookup structure before the `map`
- `itemList` seems like a terrible name, I would call it `categories`

I would counter-propose the following;

```js
const items = [{name: 'test', value: 1, category: 'a'}, {name: 'test2', value: 2, category: 'b'}, {name: 'test3', value: 3, category: 'c'}];
const categories = {testnum1: {name: 'test123', category: 'a'}, testnum2: {name: 'test234', category: 'b'}};
                    
function getCategorizedItems(items, categories){
  //Desired output; [{name: 'test', itemCategory: 'testnum1'},{name: 'test2', itemCategory: 'testnum2'}]
  const categoriesMap = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(categories).map((entry) => [entry[1].category, entry[0]]));
  return items.map(item => ({name: item.name, itemCategory:categoriesMap[item.category]})).filter(item => item.itemCategory);
}

console.log(getCategorizedItems(items, categories));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would start by extracting the relevant data from `itemList` and create a lookup object that maps the `category` to the relevant key/itemCategory.

```
const itemCategories = new Map(
  Object.entries(itemList)
    .map(([itemCategory, {category}]) => [category, itemCategory])
);
```

With the above structure you can `filter` the `items` and only keep the items that have a `category` property that is present within the lookup object. After filtering the array you can `map` the data into the desired result.

```
items
  .filter(item => itemCategories.has(item.category))
  .map(item => ({
    name: item.name,
    itemCategory: itemCategories.get(name.category)
  }));
```

```js
const items = [{name: 'test', value: 1, category: 'a'}, {name: 'test2', value: 2, category: 'b'}, {name: 'test3', value: 3, category: 'c'}];
const itemList = {testnum1: {name: 'test123', category: 'a'}, testnum2: {name: 'test234', category: 'b'}};

const itemCategories = new Map(
  Object.entries(itemList)
    .map(([itemCategory, {category}]) => [category, itemCategory])
);

function getCategorizedItems(items) {
  return items
    .filter(item => itemCategories.has(item.category))
    .map(item => ({
      name: item.name,
      itemCategory: itemCategories.get(item.category)
    }));
}

console.log(getCategorizedItems(items));
```

Answer (score 2):

There is some very bad naming in the code. Names are too long and have overlapping abstractions. What is a category, there are two types  `a`, `b`, or `c` and  `testnum1` and `itemNum2`

Due to poor naming the function has lost so much semantic accuracy it takes a second look to see what it is doing.

### What are you doing?

`getCategorizedItems` getting categorized items??

- From the input example all items are already categorized. So the function is not really getting categorized items
- The output has new categories `"a"` becomes `"test123"` so the items are being recategorized (or because there is a one to one match the cats are being transformed)
- Each item is restructured, From `{name: 'test', value: 1, category: 'a'}` to  `{name: 'test', category: 'testnum1'}`
- Items are filtered by existence of transformed category names.

### Rename

Naming the function `transformCategoriesRestructureAndFilter` is impractical so `recategorize` could be more apt within the context of the code

As you are using `category` as an identifier, you should make it clear `categoryId` or `catId`, or even just `id`. Thus

```
// ignoring irrelevant data
itemList = {testnum1: {catId: 'a'}, testnum2: {catId: 'b'}}; 
items = [{name: '1', catId: 'a'},{name: '2', catId: 'b'},{name: '3', catId: 'c'}];
```

#### Use appropriate data structures

The object `itemList` is a transformation and should be a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for quick lookup. Either defined as such

```
const catIdTransform = new Map((["a", "testnum1"], ["b", "testnum2"]]);
```

Or constructed from `itemList`

```
const catIdTransform = new Map(Object.entries(itemList).map(([name, {catId}]) => [catId, name]));
```

### Rewrite

Thus you can rewrite using the new naming.

First transform the `catId` and then filter items without new ids.

```
function recategorize(items, idMap) {
    return items.map(item => ({...item, catId: idMap.get(item.catId)}))
        .filter(({catId}) => catId);
}
```

#### Working example

Using renamed data structures.

```js
const items = [{name: '1', catId: 'a'},{name: '2', catId: 'b'},{name: '3', catId: 'c'}];
const catIdTransform = new Map([["a", "num1"], ["b", "num2"]]);

function recategorize(items, idMap) {
    return items.map(item => ({...item, catId: idMap.get(item.catId)}))
        .filter(({catId}) => catId);
}

console.log(recategorize(items, catIdTransform));
```

or if you are forced to maintain the naming and existing data

```js
const items = [{name: '1', category: 'a'}, {name: '2', category: 'b'}, {name: '3', category: 'c'}];
const itemList = {testnum1: {category: 'a'}, testnum2: {category: 'b'}}; 
const categoryTransform = new Map(Object.entries(itemList).map(([name, {category}]) => [category, name]));

function categorizedItems(items, idMap) {  // at least drop the get
    return items.map(item => ({...item, category: idMap.get(item.category)}))
        .filter(({category}) => category);
}

console.log(categorizedItems(items, categoryTransform));
```